# Pass Multiple parameters in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form send POST data to an action, so I creating an action with multiple parameters is a `FormCollection` and a string. But I don't know how to pass it into AJAX jQuery.

This is my action method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form, string CodeName)
{
        List<Product> PList = (List<Product>)TempData["PListIndex"];
        var index = PList.FindIndex(c => c.Code == CodeName);
        PList[index].NameProduct = form[0];
        PList[index].Price = form[1];
        PList[index].Madein = form[2];

        if (FileFactory.Save(PList, @"DATA\CSDL.DAT"))
            return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return Json("Failed to Save", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my Ajax jQuery:

```
function sendformdata() {
     var form = $("#Edit").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "FileEx")',
            data: { form: form, CodeName: _codename } // I don't know how to pass these two parameters
            success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use a proper model, not `FormCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()`, then you can add additional elements to the array.

```js
function sendformdata() {
  var form = $("#Edit").serializeArray();
  form.push({ name: "CodeName", value: _codename});
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "FileEx")',
    data: form,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
}
```